# Connecting to IIS from virtual machine inside vmwate

Tags: iis, vmware

I have a virtual machine running windows xp inside a vmware instance. How do i connect to the iis on my vmware instance from my xp virtual machine?

Hope you get the idea, otherwise ill elaborate.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to know the ip of the machine that hosts the iis. then a simple http:\xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx\ or http:\machinename